# Can I use jquery to on image hover fade on load text to new text dependent on each image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 6 images that when hovered on I would like there corresponding text to fadeIn in the same position one overtaking the other on each image hover.

I am able to show/hide on hover but I am unable to get each element to remove when a new image is hovered.

I have been working on a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/PvVg9/

I am new to jquery and the help would really be appreciated.

```
$('.trigger').hover(function() {
    $('.hide').fadeOut(function() {
        $('.panel').fadeIn();
    });
});
$('.trigger-two').hover(function() {
    $('.hide').fadeOut(function() {
        $('.panel-two').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for jQuery if you are happy to use CSS3:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PvVg9/155/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="trigger">Image 1<div class="panel">SHOW ME 1</div></div>
<div class="trigger">Image 2<div class="panel">SHOW ME 2</div></div>
<div class="trigger">Image 3<div class="panel">SHOW ME 3</div></div>
<div class="trigger">Image 4<div class="panel">SHOW ME 4</div></div>
<div class="trigger">Image 5<div class="panel">SHOW ME 5</div></div>
<div class="trigger">Image 6<div class="panel">SHOW ME 6</div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.panel,
.trigger {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 2px;
}

.trigger {
    position: relative;
    background: grey;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.panel {
    position: absolute;
    left:     100%;
    top:      -3px;
    background-color: red;
    border:   1px solid darkred;
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:   0;
    transition: visibility 0.1s linear 0.5s,opacity 0.5s linear;
}

.trigger:hover .panel {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    transition-delay:0s;
}
```

Or if you want them one on top of the other then: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PvVg9/156/)

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what you want, I guess a tooltip JQuery plug may fit your need.
Check this [tool](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/).

I also update your example, you can have a look at it jsfiddle.net/PvVg9/154/

Comment: Thanks For the Update, This is the site i am working on. http://19610.hs-sites.com/meet-the-team if you look directly below the navigation bar there is a title and quote and then to the right 6 icons. I would like that quote to fade into different text when you hover on one of the icons. Each icon is going to have it's own text.